# Why would a TPMS sensor start working again?

Tags: toyota, tires, rav4, tire-pressure, tire-pressure-monitoring-system

I have a 2008 Toyota RAV4.  One day, the TPMS warning light came on.  I then checked the pressure in all of my tires, including the spare.  All were ~34 psig, which is plenty of pressure.

I went to a tire shop, and they scanned each of my tires for the TPMS sensor.  The TPMS sensor in my back left tire was non-responsive.

---

I didn't have it replaced for a while.  I just drove around with my TPMS warning light on, and regularly manually checked my tire pressure.

Then, about a week later, suddenly I noticed my TPMS warning light was no longer on.  I checked my tires, all were still inflated.

---

I am very happy this happened, as I don't have to replace my tires yet.  However, I started wondering why the sensor started working again.  I can't seem to find this information on the internet anywhere.

I am wondering: **does anyone know why a TPMS sensor would start working again?**

My best theory is that the battery inside the sensor died, but then somehow rebounded, as I have observed batteries do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your theory on the battery dying and then rebounding is one possibility and it's not uncommon for a nearly end-of-life battery or the unit it is powering to exhibit unpredictable behavior.

The other possibility that comes to my mind is an intermittent connection, either to the battery or some other component in the sensor.

In either case your best first step is to rebuild the unit (and the other 3 as well) or have it rebuilt at a tire shop.  Generally this involves replacing the battery and the seals.